# Parse sentences with [value](type) format

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse and extract key, values from a given sentence which follow the following format:
`I want to get [samsung](brand) within [1 week](duration) to be happy.`

I want to convert it into a split list like below:
`['I want to get ', 'samsung:brand', ' within ', '1 week:duration', ' to be happy.']`

I have tried to split it using `[` or `)` :

```
re.split('\[|\]|\(|\)',s)
```

which is giving output:

```
['I want to get ',
 'samsung',
 '',
 'brand',
 ' within ',
 '1 week',
 '',
 'duration',
 ' to be happy.']
```

and

```
re.split('\[||\]|\(|\)',s)
```

is giving below output :

```
['I want to get ', 
'samsung](brand) within ', 
'1 week](duration) to be happy.']
```

Any help is appreciated.

Note: This is similar to stackoverflow inline links as well where if we type : `go to [this link](http://google.com)` it parse it as link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As first step we split the string, and in second step we modify the string:

```
s = 'I want to get [samsung](brand) within [1 week](duration) to be happy.'

import re

s = re.split('(\[[^]]*\]\([^)]*\))', s)
s = [re.sub('\[([^]]*)\]\(([^)]*)\)', r'\1:\2', i) for i in s]

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
['I want to get ', 'samsung:brand', ' within ', '1 week:duration', ' to be happy.']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a two step approach: process the `[...](...)` first to format as needed and protect these using some rare/unused chars, and then split with that pattern.

Example:

```
s = "I want to get [samsung](brand) within [1 week](duration) to be happy.";
print(re.split(r'｟([^｟｠]+)｠', re.sub(r'\[([^][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)', r'｟\1:\2｠', s)))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HPaLPc)

The `\[([^\][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)` pattern matches

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^\][]*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]\(` - `](` substring
- `([^()]*)` - Group 2 (`$2`): any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)`  - a `)` char.

The `｟([^｟｠]+)｠` pattern just matches any `｟...｠` substring but keeps what is in between as it is captured.

Comment: thanks for the answer, why have you placed `｟` and `｠` ??

Comment: @sid8491 To delimit the substrings that should be split against.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `](` pattern first, then split on `[)` characters
`re.replace('\)\[', ':').split('\[|\)',s)`

Answer (score 1):

One approach, using `re.split` with a lambda function:

```
sentence = "I want to get [samsung](brand) within [1 week](duration) to be happy."
parts = re.split(r'(?<=[\])])\s+|\s+(?=[\[(])', sentence)

processTerms = lambda x: re.sub('\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)', '\\1:\\2', x)
parts = list(map(processTerms, parts))
print(parts)

['I want to get', 'samsung:brand', 'within', '1 week:duration', 'to be happy.']
```